# Empty $_POST while sending data in POST-request with curl (command line) to php-script

Tags: php, curl, post

I am currently trying to send a POST-request to a PHP-script on a VPS. The request is made with curl and looks like this:

```
curl -L -X POST --cacert /home/user/server.pem --data "analysis_results=1" http://server-ip-here/api/v2/update_analysis_results.php
```

The PHP-Script only contains the following:

```
<?php

echo "Helloooo World!";

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    print_r($_POST);
    if ( !empty($_POST) ) {
            echo "post";
    }
}
?>
```

After executing the curl command the following is returned:

```
Helloooo World!Array
(
)
```

I can't figure out why the $_POST-Array is empty. Any ideas?

Edit: replaced, "echo $_POST" with "print_r($_POST)"

Comment: You cannot echo out an array in PHP. [`$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is an array. You can use either [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

Comment: Can you please try `-F "analysis_results=1"` instead of `--data "analysis_results=1"`?

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev in that case curl says the following: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: analysis_results=1
`

Answer (score 0):

you should use print_r($_POST) instead of echo $_POST;

$_POST is an array.

echo $_POST['analysis_results'];

Comment: I tried accessing the field already but the array is indeed empty